# Making an object hang

Tags: unity

This image is pretty self explanatory I hope:

[image]

How can I achieve this effect without animating it? I want to avoid animations as there are many objects hanging and I dont want them to move the exact same way.

Comment: The object just needs to rotate randomly? Or it needs to react to objects pushing against it as well?

Comment: No reaction is needed. Basically, what I want is make these swing slightly: http://i.imgur.com/s7k6zGX.png - they are train hand grips, or should be.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [`HingeJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html).

Note that when you want it to start swinging, you need to give it a little push in form of a small impulse (like with [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) on Start, for example).

Comment: It worked! Kinda, how do I make the motion perpetual? After some swings it will stop.

Comment: @Lechinor You could add a script which adds random forces to them in random intervals. In moving trains these grips swing around because the train accelerates, decelerates, drives through curves and over rough rails, which translates to forces acting on them and making them swing. In a real train, almost the same forces act on each grip, but they still swing slightly asynchronously because due to cheap manufacturing and wear they all have slightly different friction-behavior. You could simulate this by slightly randomizing the drag parameters of each Rigidbody.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this idea will work for you, but could you use a single animation and randomly offset starting point of it for each handle? They won't sync up because they are all randomly offset. Of course, if you want them to swing to the train movement, this may not look so good.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve a more organic movement than I would get by animating it, but thanks.